# Aggregate pandas dataframe by a column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this

[image]

I want to aggregate this so that I just have this

[image]

How would I do this with pandas?

Comment: By `groupby` using the `sum` or `count` aggregator and `Tract` column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `pd.DataFrame.groupby`, and then agg with `last` and `sum`

```
df.groupby('Tract').agg({'Year':'last','a':'sum','b':'sum','c':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
       Year     a   b   c
Tract               
1111    2016    5   5   5
```